# Does $\mathcal{KL}(D)$ admit the "yanking" axiom

Tags: pr.probability, ct.category-theory, quantum-mechanics

Bob Coecke made the "yanking" axiom famous as he applied it to teleportation in Quantum Computing:

[image: The Yanking Axiom for Symmetric Monoidal Categories]

[image: The Yanking Axiom for Symmetric Monoidal Categories]

This is normally presented on the category of Hilbert spaces, and so here is a derivation of the yanking rule on Hilb:

[image]

I am interested to know if the yanking axiom is admitted by the Kleisli Category of the Distribution monad, $\mathcal{KL}(D)$.  A good description of this category can be found in [Jacobs and Furber "Towards a categorical account of conditional probability."](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0831.pdf).

[image]

Much work has been done to find the axioms for  $\mathcal{KL}(D)$ and categories like it, as you can see in [Fritz, Tobias. "A synthetic approach to Markov kernels, conditional independence and theorems on sufficient statistics."](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07021.pdf) as well as [Jacobs, Bart, A. Palmigiano, and M. Sadrzadeh. "Multisets and distributions, in drawing and learning."](http://www.cs.ru.nl/B.Jacobs/PAPERS/multisets-distributions-jacobs.pdf)

What I know so far is that $\mathcal{KL}(D)$ is symmetric monoidal and has cups like this $I \rightarrow X \otimes Y$, it might even have a dagger which would give it caps like this $X \otimes Y \rightarrow I$.  If $\mathcal{KL}(D)$ had conditionals, then it would have a functorial dagger. Even if it did, though, you have to then prove that these interact in the right way to get yanking.

Comment: Could you spell out what the yanking axiom says? Does it just say that every object in your symmetric monoidal category is dualizable? For that matter, I think it would help make your question more self-contained if you could spell out what the distribution monad is -- in particular, what category is it a monad on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added a proof that a certain category satisfies the "yanking axiom", and I *think* I can infer that it simply says that every object in your symmetric monoidal category is [dualizable](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dualizable+object). I'm not sure, though. If the "yanking axiom" means something different, then the following may be moot.

Anyway, if that is what the "yanking axiom" says, then I believe the answer to your question is *no*. The symmetric monoidal structure on $KL(D)$ which you have in mind presumably is the one lifting the cartesian monoidal structue on $Set$, where $X \otimes_{KL(D)} Y = X \times Y$. Under this monoidal structure, the monoidal unit is the one-element set $1$. Moreover, $1$ is terminal in $KL(D)$. If $X$ is dualizable, then its dual $X^\vee$ is given by the internal hom $X^\vee = [X, 1]$. I don't think that internal homs exist in general in $KL(D)$ (although I believe that $[X,Y]$ exists when $X$ is a finite set), but since $1$ is terminal, the internal $[X,1]$ certainly exists and is given by $1$. So if $X$ is dualizable, then it dual is the terminal object $1$. That is, there is at most one dualizable object up to isomorphism. The unit of a monoidal category is always dualizable, so in this case we see that $1$ is the unique dualizable object of $KL(D)$.

Comment: Thanks Tim!  That helps.