# What natural language properties are supported by these categorical axioms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, computational-linguistics, linguistics

I find it difficult to see a concise description of all the Categorical structures one needs to support each of the features we see in Natural Language.  This work was largely covered by Coecke and Sadrzadeh, but I would like to have a concise compendium here.  I will list the categorical axioms that we see proposed in Coecke and Sadrzadeh's work and I would like it if someone could give the Natural Language feature each axiom is necessary for along with examples in the English language.

1. Symmetric Monoidal structure (Hedges and Sadrzadeh, *[A Generalised Quantifier Theory of Natural Language in Categorical Compositional Distributional Semantics with Bialgebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01635)*)
2. Internal comonoids, or bialgebras (Hedges–Sadrzadeh)
3. Yanking ([Does $\mathcal{KL}(D)$ admit the "yanking" axiom](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409479/does-mathcalkld-admit-the-yanking-axiom))
4. Compactness (Hedges–Sadrzadeh)
5. Closedness (Hedges–Sadrzadeh)
6. Rigidness (de Felice–Toumi–Coecke, *[DisCoPy: Monoidal Categories in Python](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.02975)*)
7. Internal Frobenius Algebras (Kartsaklis–Sadrzadeh–Pulman–Coecke, *[Reasoning about Meaning in Natural Language with Compact Closed Categories and Frobenius Algebras](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.5980)*)
8. (In the reverse sense) What is the categorical structure that supports Disambiguation? (Wang–Sadrzadeh–Abramsky–Cervantes, *[On the Quantum-like Contextuality of Ambiguous Phrases](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.14589)*)

Comment: I put in the paper titles, because people who are likely to be able to answer your question will recognise those easier on sight, and also without clicking through to download a pdf to see.

Comment: To the general public: let me know if there is any interest in a bounty.